# OAuth2 to Sandbox community with `refresh_token` - requested scope not available

Tags: community, oauth2, sandbox

I am using Salesforce Mobile SDK for iOS which uses OAuth 2.0 User-Agent Flow.

When authenticating against a community, the URL looks like so

```
https://<Community>/<OptionalPath>/services/oauth2/authorize?client_id=<ClientId>&redirect_uri=https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success&display=touch&device_id=<iOS VendorId>&response_type=token&scope=full%20refresh_token
```

The connected app callback uri is set to `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`

This works fine when connecting to Community in Production.

However, if i connect to community in my sandbox, i get an error

> error=invalid_scope&error_description=the%20requested%20scope%20is%20not%20available

If i take out `refresh_token` scope, the redirect to Login works just fine.

However, the SDK requires a refresh_token to work.

What can i do **without changing redirect uri** (as this is an app we already shipped to thousands of users) so that the app works with Sandbox community?

Comment: As per https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_user_agent_flow.htm&type=5  "The refresh token for the user-agent flow is only issued if you requested scope=refresh_token and one of the following scenarios is true"  If the redirect URL doesn't fall under the provided categories, I believe it wouldn't work

Comment: Can you clarify if the app's vendor has the ability to specify the redirect URI without changing the app(Like for example the Salesforce app lets you specify the environment. When doing so it chooses the correct redirect URI)?